# Trouble getting Liveness Probe working for GKE non-http Docker build

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a process building successfully with Docker but that always fails the deployment step.

The process is a non-http quickly-running sweep of some files ... I tried adding a TCP liveness and readiness probe to the **deploy.yaml** in the /kubernetes directory for the GKE automated deployment setup.

I also: reversed the exit codes (was returning 1 on success so I made this 0 as Kubernetes expects) ...

Started with two threads: one a tcp server that does **serve_forever** at the end and the other the real work process, with extra **sleep** to let Kubernetes catch up ...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = Thread(target=main, args=(None,None))
    t2 = Thread(target=tcpserve, args=([1]), daemon=True)
    t.start()
    t2.start()
```

I'm just about out of arrows on this; any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question? Screenshots, what troubleshooting have you done? Documentations that you are trying to follow. Does it show some error prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

The Tcp server I was using I started like this:

```
 aServer         = socketserver.TCPServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), MyTCPRequestHandler)
```

But instead it needed to be this:

```
 aServer         = socketserver.TCPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), MyTCPRequestHandler)
```

*splut* ... I should have seen this earlier!!!